# PHP easier way to hide/show menu items to logged in / logged out users

Tags: php

Is there an easier more efficient way to hide/show menu items to logged in, logged out users? It seems like I should not have to copy the whole menu again with duplicate menu items. The menu items maybe in different order like below

You can see in my example below I have added to links in the `<?php } else { ?>` statement

```
<?php
    if($_SESSION["loggedIn"] == "yes") { 
    ?>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="retailers.php">Stores</a></li>
      <li><a href="coupons.php">Coupons</a></li>
      <li><a href="featured.php">Featured Offers</a></li>
      <li><a href="howitworks.php">How It Works</a></li>
      <li><a href="help.php">Help</a></li>
    </ul>

    <?php } else { ?>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="retailers.php">Stores</a></li>
          <li><a href="coupons.php">Coupons</a></li>
          <li><a href="myaccount.php">My Account</a></li>//logged in item
          <li><a href="featured.php">Featured Offers</a></li>
          <li><a href="howitworks.php">How It Works</a></li>
          <li><a href="help.php">Help</a></li>
          <li><a href="myfavorites.php">My Favorite Stores</a></li>//logged in item
        </ul>
    <?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Updated for new ordering of items:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="retailers.php">Stores</a></li>
  <li><a href="coupons.php">Coupons</a></li>
  <?php
  if($_SESSION["loggedIn"] == "yes") { 
      echo '<li><a href="myaccount.php">My Account</a></li>';
  }
  ?><li><a href="featured.php">Featured Offers</a></li>
  <li><a href="howitworks.php">How It Works</a></li>
  <li><a href="help.php">Help</a></li>  
  <?php
  if($_SESSION["loggedIn"] == "yes") { 
      echo '<li><a href="myfavorites.php">My Favorite Stores</a></li>';
  }
  ?>  

</ul>
```

Comment: One issue with that, I would like be able to move the links around in a different order

Comment: Well, that's not what your example showed, or your question was asking about.

Comment: Sorry I will adjust the question, I just put them at the end because I was copying and pasting, I will rewrite it

Comment: I'm guessing it's still going to be about this simple.

Comment: probably will be, just a novice, trying to learn :) thanks for your help. I just edited it, hope that makes sense.

Comment: I updated my answer. As you can see it's pretty simple. You put stuff where you want it. What you may want to eventually do is put these in an array or a database table to store who can see what links when.

Comment: Thanks Jess!!  Good idea on the array, I just learned how put an array in a page, so that might not be too hard.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than cluttering up the code, you can place the html into multiple PHP files that are loaded in dependant on the logged in user...

```
switch($_SESSION['userLevel']) {
    case "guest": //Not logged in
        require_once('guestnav.php');
        break;
    case "user": //regular user
        require_once('usernav.php');
        break;
    case "admin": //admin nav
        require_once('adminnav.php');
        break;
    //etc and default nav below
}
```

then in the nav php files just put the HTML with no PHP and it will be loaded in when the proper criteria is met. makes managing multiple navigation menu's easy.