# How to load a HTML-page into a DIV by clicking a Li from inside a menu on an 'include('menu.html')'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I have an application that has 'guest' and 'user' content. I built a menuIn.html and a menuOut.html (for logged-in/out) and called them from within a html  of my MainPage.php in the following way. (suggested from:     [PHP easier way to hide/show menu items to logged in / logged out users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711891/php-easier-way-to-hide-show-menu-items-to-logged-in-logged-out-users))

```
include ('includes/header.html');
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { 
include('menuIn.html');
}else{
include('menuOut.html');
}
```

When clicked, a link in menuIn.html calls a jQuery script that puts a div in the html section of the SelectedPage.php. My overall attempts aim to only change the div of the SelectedPage from the menus. Here are my attempts and references.
On all SelectedPage.php  ie: AboutUs.php: code to receive the div is:

```
<div id="target1"></div> // On AboutUs.php
<div id="target2"></div> // On FAQs.php etc.
```

menuIn.html code:

```
<li><a href="About.php" class="ajaxtrigger1">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="FAQs.php" class="ajaxtrigger2">Contact</a></li>
```

The jQuery call number1 call1.js:

```
$('.ajaxtrigger1').click(function(){
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  $('#target1').load(url);
  return false;
});
```

The files to load into the different div's are  Add1.html, Add2.html Add3.html:

"Hello World1, Hello World2, 3 etc."

All files are stored in the same directory and jQuery.js and call1.js, call2.js etc. are reference in the head. I've gotten it to work if the menu was not in an include('file.html') but then I don't have the possibility of menu displying links for logged in/out users.

Researched:

- http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/bNx4g/2/  (This seems close but badly commented)
- [How to load a button from external page into a div content using Jquery load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308599/how-to-load-a-button-from-external-page-into-a-div-content-using-jquery-load)
- [How to load a HTML-page into a DIV by clicking a Li inside a menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588976/how-to-load-a-html-page-into-a-div-by-clicking-a-li-inside-a-menu)

I am open to any suggestions including a full re-write. Please re-read my overall aim and all help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If possible then please add your fiddle

Comment: so when clicked `.ajaxtrigger1` it should render `add1.html` to `#target1` div?

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? Click event fires properly? Server responds correctly?

Comment: Fiddle example is not complete because there is no place to put the external file 'loadFile' see: http://jsfiddle.net/5thfeb/62npjqrb/

Comment: Reply to Harsh Makani....... yes that is the idea. Thank you

Comment: To Anton F, only the header displays no <div> because I can't properly put a reference back to the SelectedPage.php from the 'include('menuIn.html') page and call1.js also needs proper referencing. Thank U.

Answer (score 0):

Found my error.
The reference to the call1.js needs to be within the body tags (I have now placed it at the bottom body tag) and not within the head tags.
Works there but not in the head tag! Thank you for all your help.

```
<body>
General code....then
<script src="call1.js"></script>
<script src="call2.js"></script>
<script src="call3.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why you are using javascript.Instead of javascript just use the iframes.Like this.

```
<iframe name="iframe_a"></iframe>
<iframe name="iframe_b"></iframe>
<li><a href="About.php" target="iframe_a">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="FAQs.php" target="iframe_b">Contact</a></li>
```

Through this way you can easily show data of different pages on a single page.

Comment: He don't want to show all the images instantly! Has asked `on click` of some `LI`